# Display message after successful delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display a message after a record has been successfully deleted. I tried everything but without success.

I have an external `js` file from which I call a `PHP` file that deletes the record.

JS file:-

```
        // Delete records
    function DeleteGoal(ids) {
        $.post("ajax/deletegoal.php", {
                userid: ids.user_id,
                goalid: ids.goal_id
            },
            function (data, status) {
                // reload goals 
                ShowGoals();
            }
        );
        var jsuccess = $("#myPhpValue").val();
        console.log(jsuccess);
}
```

PHP file:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['goalid']))
    {
        // include Database connection file 
        require('../../login_system/db.php');

        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $goal_id = $_POST['goalid'];

       // $query = "DELETE from goals where user_id = '$userid' AND goal_id='$goal_id'";

      //  if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
           // exit(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   //     }

        $success = "true";
        echo '<form><input type="hidden" id="myPhpValue" value="'.$success.'"/></form>';

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }  
?>
```

I tried to send the $success variable back to `js` file with several ways but none worked. It seems that any output command (echo, alert, console.log) doesn't display anything and I don't know why.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: you need to learn basics about async javascript. js doesnt wait for ajax to finish before processing the stuff after your post

Comment: put `console.log(data)` right after `//reload goals`

Comment: console.log(data) doesn't display anything

Comment: As Emeeus said, you need to put `console.log(data);` in the callback function i.e. right after(or before) `//reload goals`. Since the ajax post call of yours is asynchronous you won't get anything from your current `console.log(data);`. If you still do not get any output, then 1. Try `console.log('data from ajax post:',data);` This will confirm that the function is getting executed if it logs at least  'data from ajax post:'. 2. Something is wrong at PHP end, try `echo 'test;' exit;` at the beginning of the PHP file.

Comment: It doesn't echo anything. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return using echo and display the response directly :

**a.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['goalid']))
    {
        ...
        echo true;
    }  
?>
```

**A.js:**

```
function DeleteGoal(ids) {
    $.post("ajax/deletegoal.php", {
            userid: ids.user_id,
            goalid: ids.goal_id
        },
        function (response) {
            if( response ){
                // reload goals 
                ShowGoals();
                console.log("Success message");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

You could return a json format what gives you the ability to return multiple info like :

**A.js:**

```
function DeleteGoal(ids) {
    $.post("ajax/deletegoal.php", {
            userid: ids.user_id,
            goalid: ids.goal_id
        },
        function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);

            if( response.success ){
               // reload goals 
                ShowGoals();

                console.log(response.message);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**a.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['goalid']))
    {
        echo jdon_encode(['success'=>true,"message"=>"Deleted Successfully"]);
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Thank all for your answers. As I wrote I use two files. A.js and a .php. I can't mix them.

Comment: You don't have to mix nothing here

Answer (score 0):

finally I did it!

PHP file

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['goalid']))
     {
        // include Database connection file 
        require('../../login_system/db.php');

        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $goalid = $_POST['goalid'];

        $query = 'DELETE from goals where userid ='.$userid.' AND goal_id='.$goalid;

        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
           exit(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }      

        $data = true;
        echo($data);

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }  
?>
```

JS file

```
// Delete records
function DeleteGoal(ids) {
    $.post("ajax/deletegoal.php", {
            userid: ids.user_id,
            goalid: ids.goal_id
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // reload goals 
            if (data==true && status =="success")
                ShowGoals();
            else
                alert("Problem");
        }
    );
}
```

So, I return what happen using *data* variable.